# How to highlight multiple words with the Highlight Text Area plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I've been using the [Highlight Text Area plugin](http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/examples.html), but I'm having some problems to highlight multiple words, see code below:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="5">communications nibh quis software & framework Quisque convallis communication skills vulputate. 
auctor blandit luctus.</textarea>

<script>
 $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
  words: ['software & framework', 'communication','communications','communication skills'],

});
</script>
```

Here are the results highlighted in bold:

**communication**s nibh quis software & framework Quisque convallis **communication** skills vulputate. 
auctor blandit luctus.

As you can see only "communication" is highlighted while I'd like to have the following results:

**communications** nibh quis **software & framework** Quisque convallis **communication skills** vulputate. auctor blandit luctus.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this jQuery plugin. But after setting up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lawlesss/kz4n6L3y/12/), and "fiddling" around. Looks like the plugin matches based on priority of the order of the matches. Update your code to the below and it will work.

```
$('textarea').highlightTextarea({
    words: ['communication skills', 'communications', 'software & framework', 'communication'],
});
```